# why it prints "Payable 2" while it should be" Payable 0"

Tags: c

I made a function named juice which lets the customer choose the cup size for 
their juice and return the price or payable amount, but there is something wrong when I choose the default case of the switch statement it should return 0 but the output is 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int juice(char size , int qty){
int price =0;
switch(size){
    //'s' for small size of cup
    case 's':
        printf("size small");
        price =20*qty;
        return price; 
        break;
    //'m' for medium size of cup
    case 'm':
        printf("size medium");
        price =30*qty;
        return price;
        break;
    //'l' for large size of cup
    case 'l':
        printf("size large");
        price =40*qty;
        return price;
        break;
    //if costumer choose wrong size
    default:
        printf("choose proper size");
    }

printf("\n%d", price);
}

int main()
{
    int price =juice('d' ,5);
    printf("\npayable is  %i\n", price);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 choose proper size
 0
 payble is  2
```

Comment: When `size` isn't a valid choice, you don't return anything, which means that `price` will probably be a garbage value. Explictily return `0` at the end of the function. (And you don't need to ´break` out of the switch after you `return` -- the `break` cannot be reached, becase you have returned from the function.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the function is not returning in the `default` case. That is undefined behavior.

Note that `return price;` makes the following `break;` unnecessary, and it also makes the code harder to read, instead and since you are setting `price`'s value in every case (*except the `default`*) you can just put `return price;` at the end. And finally, add a initialization statement in the `default` case.

Something like this

```
int juice(char size, int qty)
{
    int price = 0;
    switch (size) {
        case 's': // 's' for small size of cup
            printf("size small\n");
            price = 20 * qty; 
            break;
        case 'm': // 'm' for medium size of cup
            printf("size medium\n");
            price = 30 * qty;
            break;
        case 'l': // 'l' for large size of cup
            printf("size large\n");
            price = 40 * qty;
            break;
        default: // if costumer choose wrong size
            printf("choose proper size\n");
            price = -1; // Invalid value?
            break;
    }
    return price;
}
```

Also, the new line character `'\n'` is meant to be placed at the end of a line, IO streams are line buffered so that would flush the stream and create a new line and it makes more sense to place the at the end.

Comment: But i think the garbage value should not be same every time when i compile , but it is.

Comment: @ShivamSingh: the wonderful thing about undefined behaviour is that it can be consistent or inconsistent as it decides, and your code is still wrong and the result still right, because the required result is undefined.

Comment: @ShivamSingh, that's the thing about *undefined* that no one seems to understand. It's in principle predictable, but not from the code itself. Note that computer programs are deterministic, so unless you change something that affects the generated program, that will not change.

Comment: You can't intentionally change that, you don't know what exactly will trigger the change. Undefined behavior is that, UNDEFINED. It doesn't matter if it behaves the same after you compile the program with a thousand changes or not, it's still undefined behavior.